# Grafana field name override

Tags: grafana

I have a time series dashboard in grafana which queries Snowflake. It displays field labels like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT C.USER_ID) {CAROUSEL_ID="1234", VIDEO_ID="video-1234"}
```

However, I only want each data point to have the display name as video_id, like "video-1234". How can I accomplish this? the docs are not quite clear in my opinion. Thanks.